# Make everything fade / blur besides a div

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make the same effect as when using a Lightbox.

The effect that i want is when you click on an image, everything looks blur besides the image in the center of the screen.

If it's done with JS please give an example with jQuery.

DEMO: http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/
(click on an image).

Comment: That effect is not a blur; it's simply a slightly opaque mask placed over the viewport and then the items in question layered on top of that.

Comment: ok, but how can i do that? :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, thanks mate but i have managed to do it on my own :)

I wrote a short script which simply fades the site's `DIV` to 0.5 and then fade in the `div` I wanted out side of the main `DIV`, and it works!

See the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#messagesLink').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function (){
        $('#messageBox').fadeIn();
    });
});

$('#exitLink').click(function() {
    $('#messageBox').fadeOut(function (){
        $('#wrapper').fadeTo('slow', 1); 
    });
});
</script>
<div id="messageBox" style="display: none; width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50%; margin-left: -150px; background-color: white; text-align: center; z-index: 9999">
    This is a text box! <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="exitLink">Click here to close!</a>.
</div>
<div id="wrapper" class="adminMainWrapper" style="z-index: -1">
    You have <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="messagesLink">5 new messages</a>
</div>
```

Now all I've left to do is to finish some minor things and tidy up this mess :)
Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Make these changes using JavaScript's setAttribute() to the new img element created using createElement() and appendChild().

CSS

```
body {
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
#upp {
position: fixed;
top: 100;
left: 100;
width: 70;
height:50;
color:black;
background-color: white;
opacity:1;
z-index:1;
}
#cover {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
background-color: white;
opacity:0.7;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>this is below. :P</p>
<div id="cover"></div>
<div id="upp"><p>this should be up. way up that the previous one.</p></div>
```

Replace p element with img element and make the changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJTGN/4/) that does what you want. It's hacky as it listens for a click on the entire document.

It works by making use of two separate `z-index` values and a `.highlighted` class for your selected image. Your overlay simply needs a higher `z-index` value than the body itself, but the selected image will *itself* need to have a higher `z-index`. The images all need to be set to `position: relative`.

We can accomplish this by listening for clicks on the document and seeing if the target is an image. If it is, we remove all the `.highlighted` classes, append the overlay if it doesn't exist, or remove it if does. We then add a `.highlighted` class to the target. If the target is any other part of the document, we'll remove the overlay.

Comment: @cwolves He didn't mean blur. He meant a mask effect as you can see Tejs' comment above.

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for, i want as less as JS libraries i can use :)

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap is simply some CSS and JS so that you do not have to re-invent the wheel. Incidentally, it's also the most watched repo on GitHub: https://github.com/popular/watched

Comment: i know, but there are lots of things i don't need there so it will be junk for me :\

Comment: Here is an update that does blur, but only in Webkit Nightlies and Chrome Canary: http://jsfiddle.net/vJTGN/6/

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to blur the rest of the page content.  Now that I said that, here's how you can do it (don't do this):

A while ago I started work on an HTML-->Canvas renderer.  It's available here:
https://github.com/cwolves/CanvasRenderer.  This will take your existing page structure and render it to an HTML5 canvas (or in IE<9 to a FlashCanvas).  Fork the repo, fix all the bugs in it.

Once you have the page rendered to a canvas, blur it using http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html.  Place this canvas over the entire page, show your lightbox.

Comment: He didn't actually mean "blur".

Comment: @JoshSmith -- But it would be much more fun if he did!